# Верстка элементов разной ширины с центрированием

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сверстать верхнюю желтую строку предупреждения, чтобы средняя надпись была четко по середине? Если ширина всех трех элементов разная.

Comment: Добавьте свои попытки решения (т.е. свой код). В чём возникла проблема?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbxOBX  Но мне кажется это не правильный способ, так как одинаковая ширина для всех элементов.

Comment: Элементам которые по бокам можно дать одинаковую ширину, к примеру в `20%`. Левому дать свойство `justify-content:flex-start`, а правому `justify-content:flex-end`. А центральному дать `60%` и свойство `justify-content:center` Но может это не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много, но как один из (хотя и костыльно, лучше все же решить флексом)

```
<style>
.yellow {position:relative;}
.left, .right {position:absolute;margin-top:-0.5em;top:50%;}
.left {left:1em;}
.right{right:1em;}
</style>

<div class="yellow">
 <div class="left">Предупреждаем:</div>
  <i class="icon icon-info-circle"></i> БАД, не является лекарственным средством
 <div class="right">&times;</div>
</div>
```

Идею подал, подпиливать напильником